# Which design pattern(elegant way) should I use for the following use case?

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-boot, transactions, spring-aop

I have a big Entity object in my web project.(JAVA spring, hibernate, spring-boot) On update of a field in POJO object, I have to push some events to queue and do some actions non transactionally.

I have two questions

1. Right Now I am planning to write an aspect object which does these non transactional actions and event pushing. I have @transactional on service layer methods(for which the aspects are written). Does failure in these aspect methods will rollback the transaction of service layer method ?
2. I have provided two ways of updating fields in POJO Object.

   - Individual rest api for each field.
   - An api for updating entire Object.(Only not null fields will be updated here)

   In the second case I need to check whether a field is updated or not and perform event pushing for each field.(Code looks clumsy here)

Is there any elegant way of solving this problem?

Comment: could you please expect in more specific terms? this is far too abstract to understand what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define to wrap your service method firstly by aspect and then by transaction. So it will be like this:

   ```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
     BEGIN ASPECT
       METHOD
     END ASPECT
   END TRANSACTION
   ```

You can use @Order(0) annotation on an aspect to use it first.

```
@Aspect
@Order(0)
@Component
public class SomeAspect {}
```